# Android - UIL How to show loading image only when image has not cached?

Tags: android, image, caching, imageview, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Library for displaying images in Android.

I know using showImageOnLoading(img_id) in DisplayImageOptions allows ImageView to show a Loading Image while image resource is loading.

It works great when I use this option for grabbing images from internet.
However, it is poor when it loads images from cache. It shows the Loading Image just an instant, then shows the Cached Image. It is just a blink.

I don't want a blink and just show the Cached Image only(without the Loading Image) if a cached image exists.

Here is the code I used:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .cacheInMemory(false)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();
String url = "http://i2.wp.com/www.fmxexpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pullto.jpg";
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, image, options);
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that blink is caused by the process of reading the file from disk. 
What if you just cache the image in memory like this:

```
    .cacheOnDisk(false)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but I need to cache many images on Disk, therefore cacheInMemory is not an option.

Comment: What about turning on both of them ?

Comment: actually, I don't want to cache in memory, as memory is vital for some device with low memory.